# Редуцированные гласные

Tags: фонетика, транскрипция

Как думаете, уважаемые форумчане, почему за такое выполнение задания поставили "2"? Я не смогла объяснить.

Выделите жирным шрифтом буквы в словах, на месте которых произносится:

а) редуцированный 1-й степени:

мол**о**ко[мълʌко́ ], орг**а**низм[ʌргʌн'и́зм ], обр**а**мление [ʌбрʌмл'эн'иjь ], ж**а**ровня [ жʌро́вн'ъ,], **а**стр**о**номия [ ʌстрʌно́м'иjь] , коопер**а**тив [ къп'ьрʌ т'и́ф];

б) редуцированный второй степени [ъ]: б**а**рабанщик[бърʌба́н'ш'ик], п**о**дорожник [ пъдʌро́жн'ик], пр**о**изводств**о**[  пръизво́цтвъ],], майск**а**я [майскъjь], п**о**лотно[пълʌтно́,], плотн**о**[ пло́тнъ].

шелестящий[  шэыл'иес'т'а́ш'иj ]

Comment: Спросила, что за вуз, сказали, что педагогический, начальные классы.Что-то строговато к начальным классам. Или, может, контрольные заочников студенты проверяют? Такая практика тоже встречается. Но к чему же придрались?

Answer (score 1):

Людмила, лично я скептически отношусь к педагогическим вузам. Согласитесь, уровень преподавания там ниже, чем на том же факультете, но уже филологическом. Такое оформление вполне возможно. Видимо, двойку поставили за то, что первый предударный гласный принято обозначать и  так: [а]. Такое обозначение предлагает, например, учебник Литневской.***Е. И. Литневская Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников*** ***Русский язык. Весь курс. Для выпускников и абитуриентов. И.Б. Голуб.- М.: Эксмо, 2010.- 368с.*** 
  Возможно, стоит уточнить у  того, кто к вам обратился.

Comment: Ну, что Вы, за это двойки не ставят, максимум замечание.Обозначения везде разные, но ведь они же используют крышечку, если девочка так оформила. Я вообще в шоке. Чего они от неё хотят?.

Comment: Я бы вообще "отлично" поставила.

Comment: Людмила, за это даже замечание не делают. Я бы тоже "отлично'' поставил.

Answer (score 0):

На мой сугубо дилетантский взгляд, ошибки в словах: *организм, обрамление* (неотмечены первые слоги), *кооператив, производство* (неучтено зияние гласных) и *шелестящий* (первый слог не эи).

Понимаю, что ответ запоздавший, к тому же не специалист в этом вопросе, но может как раз это позволит прояснить логику проверяющего.

Comment: Первый слог - абсолютное начало, это крышечка, всё верно. шелестящий-есть ошибка - 2 позиция Ъ[ шъл'иес'т'а́ш'иj ]Но в том и загвоздка, что задание- не полная транскрипция, а выделить жирным шрифтом редуцированные 1 и 2 степени, они были выделены, ошибка 1 только в объяснении в скобках, но его и не требовалось. За что "2"?

Comment: @Людмила, я про выделения жирным шрифтом и пишу. Во всех названных мною словах не выделена жирным буква, или выделена лишняя, хотя транскрипция при этом бывает и верной. 5 ошибок в небольшом задании - это безусловная двойка.

Comment: Да нет, Вы плохо прочитали задание. Под а) выделить только редуц.1  степени, под б) 2 степени. По-моему, всего одна ошибка-шелестящий- и то не в задании, а в транскрипции, а её делать было и не надо, это уже объяснение.

Comment: А в шелестящий - это я не выделила, у неё выделено верно в первом слоге.

Comment: @Людмила я прочитал задание. Не знаю кто ошибся в выделении, но буквы "о" в словах "обрамление" и "организм" не выделены, хотя транскрипция верная. Не выделены "оо" в слове "кооператив". По поводу "производства" не уверен в правильности выделения "о" как [ъ].

Comment: Да, верно, в абсолютном начале крышечка, тоже редуц. 1 степени, не выделены О. С кооперативом не согласна, там ОО - редукция 2 степени, а нужно выделить первой. А почему сомнения в ъ в слове "производство"? - второй предударный и заударный, всё верно, всё равно с "2" не согласна.

Comment: @Людмила "Второй член зияния (вне зависимости от положения данного гласного по отношению к ударению) не может иметь
вторую степень редукции — то есть в этой ситуации не произносятся звуки типа [ъ], [ь]" http://www.philol.msu.ru/~otipl/SpeechGroup/publications/2003/z-2.doc Соответственно, 3 ошибки (кооператив, организм, обрамление).

К тому же, учитывая разноплановость ошибок в транскрипции, такое ощущение, что она делалась несамостоятельно, а надёргано из разных сайтов.

Comment: К чему такие сложности для начальных классов? Не учили они этого. К тому же, там много исключений. Вот по Вашей ссылке:"Исключение составляют частотные слова типа соображать, вооружение, сооружение, воодушевление, и некоторые другие — на месте зияния может произноситься один звук [а]. Причем в спонтанной быстрой речи в этих словах на месте зияния может произноситься один сильно редуцированный звук [ъ]. По-видимому, такого рода слова прошли два этапа: сначала произошло стяжение зияния в один звук [а] (т. е. зияние исчезло ), а уже потом эти слова подчинились общему правилу произношения".

Comment: @Людмила если в задании есть зияние, значит зияния, пускай и не в полном объеме, но проходили. Студент мог не знать всех тонкостей, но понять, что при литературном произношении, на этом месте никак не редуцированный 2-й степени был должен. Я, кстати, уточнил у знакомого филолога (2003-2008 гг. обучения), говорит, что начал изучать зияния еще в 1-м полугодии на "введении в языкознание".